# Should I bring up plans to leave during a negotiation with my boss about pay?

Tags: salary, negotiation, tech-industry

I'm a developer in a tech company and have been here for only about 3 months as a contract worker. As my boss has been happy with the work I have done, he is going to discuss with me (in about a week or so) about making me a full-time employee, and to discuss my salary etc.

The issue is, I plan to further my studies in another country within a year or so and I am not sure if I should bring this up during the discussion as I'm scared that will lead to me being let go (I enjoy this workplace and the work) or having a low pay (given below market rate due to the fact I will leave in about a year or so).

How do i go about this? if i keep quiet about this and bring it up about a month or so from me leaving i feel that it is mean but i also fear the consequences of bringing it up now. Any advice?

Comment: Also related (given the possible switch from contract to full time): [Should I tell the hiring manager that I don't intend to stay for more than a year?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/74359)

Comment: Have you considered just asking to continue on a contract basis instead, possible asking for a year-long contract? Or is that not really possible? Although I still don't think you should be too specific about your future plans in that case.

Comment: I wouldn't mention plans to leave many months from now when you don't know for certain, maybe they will offer a great raise and a better position - then you'll want to stay. The idea that you'll be worth less than market rate because you're leaving seems odd, aren't you leaving and going to school so you'll be worth more - if they proved they valued you then you'd never want to leave. If there's reason enough to be dissatisfied *everyone* leaves eventually. It's when efforts are made to retain people that everyone stays. You're shortcircuiting your chances by preposturing.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't bring this up now - the impeding conversation is about what you are doing in your career **now** not what you may or may not be doing in *x* months time.

You are right to be concerned about mentioning plans for further study (or any plans that aren't "working at this company") being potentially viewed negatively as many wouldn't companies/managers wouldn't want to "invest" in someone they view as potentially having one foot out of the door already.

If/when your study plans come to fruition then you can give your appropriate amount of notice and move on, that's totally normal and there is nothing "mean" about that or unprofessional.

Comment: Thanks mate, i guess i will bring it up when the study plans are more certain rather than risking things now

Answer (score 0):

The Official answer is: Don´t ever talk about leaving, unless when you are handing in your notice. This is usually universally the best approach, as you will have disadvantages in most scenarios when you are seen as temporary worker.

There is of course an exception: Especially since you want to get further education, it can make sense to play especially nice. This is, if you are interested in working with them in the future. If you are open with them about your plans, and coming back to work there or even during your studies is a possibility for you, this may get you the support of this company in fulfilling your plans. You should have a feeling for that: Are they a company that reward honesty? Are they forward thinking and strategic? Are they open to unconventional work arrangements?

Comment: If you want to be especially nice, give them a longer notice than is customary (or required) when you decide to leave; 3 weeks instead of just 2.  If you tell management that you are leaving in a year, I would be very surprised if they invest any time or $$ in you.

Comment: @Nolo Problemo: In general I wold agree. But there are also those who are actually nice and no how to treat future talent. I know we are. We actually have a student currently and we do invest in hopes she might join in the future. ..

Comment: hmmm, i would actually know my placements into the university about two months before i would need to leave the company (as the university is overseas), i'm guessing a 1-2 month notice works as well?

Comment: @Daniel, I have not worked for these unicorns of which you speak. ;)